# custom url redirection using htaccess where subdomain exists in url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect url, if subdomain exist in current url other wise no change.

this is what i want to change

1. abc.abcd.com   change into    abcd.com/test
2. abc.abcd.com/mno   change into abcd.com/mno
3. abc.abcd.com/zyz  change into abcd.com/xyz

   Can anyone help me, am new one in htaccess

Comment: You must first consider what you want to do. And not want the opposite at the end.

Comment: sorry Croises,
  i want that my url not redirect but change the contents.

finally can u do this for me ?
   if i hit abc.xyz.com/mno   change into  xyz.com/mno

  the page url must be abc.xyz.com/mno and display the contents of zyz.com/mno

Comment: If you use the same site without redirection for all subdomains. You can do that with nothing to do and no particular `.htaccess`. And NO it's not possible to change the subdomain in the link, without redirect.

Comment: i dont want to change the url, but i want to display the contents of the page of the url without subdomain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on 
# Not for http://abcd.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcd\.com$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^$ http://abcd.com/test [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://abcd.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.

Comment: thanks for ur reply,

i have a another question,
  my sybdomain is dynamic, eg (abc.abcd.com, cdf.abcd.com, jkl.abc.com)

my subdomain is dynamic

Comment: hello Croises,
  i cant predict my subdomain, it may change user to user  ( each site member get different subdomains), cant hardcode in htaccess

Comment: I edit my answer with that. Now it's for all subdomains

Comment: hello,
  i want to get the redirect page without redirect

Comment: No, you can't do that, because you change the domain name... And you ask for "redirect" in your question. But you can change `[R=302,L]` for `[L]` (2x) and just show the new content.

Comment: And you can even delete the last line, as the content is the same. And in the end it is only a redirection to /test ...